# Adding message before shutting down the program

Tags: java

Before i close my program (press X on the frame) i wish to have a Conformation message that says something alike: "Are you sure you want to close this window" Followed by a yes and no button.

How exactly can i achieve such a thing?
Ive tried looking up a window listener but not much luck so far.

Where do i exactly play this override Windows listener? I have a seperate view and frame class.

Since i do not wish to add controls for the option pane in my frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must override the method `javax.swing.JFrame.processWindowEvent(WindowEvent)` and check for the `WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING` event ID.

Display your confirmation dialog and exit only when it returns "Yes".

[Code sample.](http://www.javafaq.nu/java-example-code-202.html)

Answer (score 1):

[WindowListener.windowClosing](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html#windowClosing%28java.awt.event.WindowEvent%29) is exactly what you want.

Attach a listener that doesn't close the frame unless the user responds positively to a [JMessagePane](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can override the `shutdown()` method.
look at this page : http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/javase/swingappfr/#code5

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use a so called Shutdown Hook, which runs after the user closed the application but before it realy shuts down, see http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/lang/hook-design.html